# Renaming Image name with PHP

Tags: php, image, upload, rename

So I'm just starting to use PHP and i pulled a script from online. the way it is setup is that if the file already exists it will not upload it. i want to be able to rename the files so it accepts all the photos.

---

Heres the Code:

```
    <?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

There is a if value that deals with the Pre existing files. I'm assuming i will change that out for a different If value to change the name? thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you Google "rename uploaded file php"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename file if the file being uploaded already exist.

```
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    $target_file=$target_file."2";//Rename file by concating any other string
    $uploadOk = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

To:

```
$target_file = $target_dir . 'this_is_my_new_name_whooah.txt';
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how we work around same named images

```
$fileCount = count (glob ("uploads/*.jpg"));
$name = ( $fileCount + 1) . '.jpg';
$newName = "uploads/" . $name;
$tf = fopen($newName, 'w');
fclose($tf);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], $newName);
```

hope this helps you out!

Comment: i tried this out and it changes the name but when i click the file in the directory it doesn't display the image. its blank.

Comment: Did you try changing $_FILES['fileField'] to $_FILES["fileToUpload"]? Also you might need to catch the file extension being uploaded and change '.jpg' to the correct file extension

Answer (score 1):

The current solution does not account for multiple similarly named files, this is a quick scalable solution.

```
if (file_exists($target_file)) 
{
    $filecounter = 0; // initialize file count.

    // runs loop increasing filecount and appending to filename until untaken filename is found.
    do
    {
        $filecounter++;
        $target_file .= " - $filecounter";
    } 
    while( file_exists($target_file) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    //echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    //$uploadOk = 0;
    rename($target_file, 'your_new_filename');
}
```